# Anything sent through segue returns nil

Tags: ios, swift, segue

Here is my code for the segue below, however all of the variables when I attempt to access them in another view controller return nil.  I even added a simple string value to send across and that returns nil too.

```
extension ViewController : MPMediaPickerControllerDelegate {
// must implement these, as there is no automatic dismissal

func mediaPicker(mediaPicker: MPMediaPickerController!, didPickMediaItems mediaItemCollection: MPMediaItemCollection!) {

    let ViewControllerhost:ViewControllerHost = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("HostViewController") as! ViewControllerHost

    let representativeItem = mediaItemCollection.representativeItem
    let title = representativeItem.title
    let artistName = representativeItem.artist

    segueInfo =
        [ "representativeItem": representativeItem
            , "title": title
            , "artistName": artistName ]

    var albumCover  = "\(MPMediaItemArtwork())"
    var songInfo = "\(MPMediaItem())"
    var messageDict = [albumCover, songInfo]

    //This sends across Album Artwork, Info, and the duration is sent from the Host view controller
    let messageData = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(messageDict, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted, error: nil)

    var error:NSError?

    appDelegate.mpcHandler.session.sendData(messageData, toPeers: appDelegate.mpcHandler.session.connectedPeers, withMode: MCSessionSendDataMode.Unreliable, error: &error)

    if error != nil{
        println("error: \(error?.localizedDescription)")
    }

     func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        if let nextVC = segue.destinationViewController as? ViewControllerHost
            , let sender = sender as? ViewController {
                /*nextVC.representativeItem_ = sender.segueInfo["representativeItem"] as? MPMediaItem
                nextVC.title_ = sender.segueInfo["title"] as! String
                nextVC.artistName_ = sender.segueInfo["artistName"] as! String*/
                nextVC.representativeItem_ = representativeItem
                nextVC.title_ = title
                nextVC.artistName_ = artistName
                nextVC.test_ = test
        }
    }

    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(ViewControllerhost, animated: true)
    })
}








func mediaPickerDidCancel(mediaPicker: MPMediaPickerController!) {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

}
```

}

Comment: Are you sure your `if let nextVC = segue.destinationViewController as? ViewControllerHost, let sender = sender as? ViewController {` conditional is executing? I'll have to check, but `sender` may not be of type ViewController...

Comment: I agree with @LyndseyScott - you have two optional bindings there, either could fail.  Have you set a breakpoint to confirm the code in the if executes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect this conditional is failing:

```
if let nextVC = segue.destinationViewController as? ViewControllerHost, let sender = sender as? ViewController {
```

Specifically the `if let sender = sender as? ViewController {` portion.

According to the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/prepareForSegue:sender:), `sender` is the button or view that triggered the segue. It's not the view controller itself, so `if let sender = sender as? ViewController {` may return false.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure if this helps but this is what I use

```
  override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if segue.identifier == "showTaskDetail" {
        let detailVC: TaskDetailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! TaskDetailViewController
        let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()
        let thisTask = fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath!) as! TaskModel
        detailVC.detailTaskModel = thisTask
        detailVC.delegate = self

    }
    else if segue.identifier == "showTaskAdd" {
        let addTaskVC:AddTaskViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! AddTaskViewController
        addTaskVC.delegate = self
    }
}
```

when you go on storyboard click on the segues and under attributes give them an identifier

maybe try this method? let me know if it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing this: 
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier(segweId, sender: self)